# Why is it looping through the 'else' in my if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

If you enable the `alert(rand)` at the bottom of my if/else statement, you will notice that when ran, it will constantly loop over the else section of my if/else statement. It's probably a simple fix, but I can't seem to figure it out. I had it working in the earlier stages of development but can't seem to figure it out now.

I'll post the code below, but it's probably easier to look at my jsfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/zAPsY/7/ Thanks.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
//You can edit the following file paths to change images in selection
var img1 = '<img src="images/luke.jpg">';
var img2 = '<img src="images/luke.jpg">';
var img3 = '<img src="images/luke.jpg">';
var img4 = '<img src="images/luke.jpg">';
var img5 = '<img src="images/luke.jpg">';
var img6 = '<img src="images/luke.jpg">';
var all = img1 + img2 + img3 + img4 + img5 + img6;

//Rotation
var speed = 0.00;
var radius = 80;
var count = 0;

$("#run").bind("click",runButtonClick);

function rotate()
{
    var centerx = $(document).width()/2;
    var centery = $(document).height()/2;           
    var num_items = $("#container > img").length;       
    $("#container > img").each(function(){
        var angle = count * (Math.PI/180);              
        var newx = centerx + Math.cos(angle)*radius - $(this).width()/2;                
        var newy = centery + Math.sin(angle)*radius - $(this).height()/2;               
        $(this).css("left",newx+"px").css("top",newy+"px");             
        count += 360/num_items + speed;
    });
}
setInterval(rotate,100/1000);

//Append elements to container
$("#appendall").click(function(){$('#container').append(all);});
$('#append').children().eq(2).click(function(){$('#container').append(img1);});
$('#append').children().eq(3).click(function(){$('#container').append(img2);});
$('#append').children().eq(4).click(function(){$('#container').append(img3);});
$('#append').children().eq(5).click(function(){$('#container').append(img4);});
$('#append').children().eq(6).click(function(){$('#container').append(img5);});
$('#append').children().eq(7).click(function(){$('#container').append(img6);});

//Refresh page
$("#reset").click(function(){location.reload();});

//IF speed is greater than 0 - ELSE add animation to div element
function runButtonClick() {
    var maxcount = 0.40;
    var incdec = 0.01;
    setInterval(function(){counter();}, 100);       
    counter()
    speed;
    function counter()
    {
        if (maxcount >= 0.00)
            {
                maxcount = maxcount - incdec;
                speed = speed + incdec;
                //alert(speed)
                //alert(maxcount)
            }               
        else if (maxcount <= 0.00)
            {   
                speed = 0.00;
                //Find amount of div elements and add 1
                var brewees = $('#container').children().length +=1;
                //get a random number
                var rand = (Math.floor(Math.random()*brewees)); 
                var ap = '20px';
                var ab = '#ddd';
                var ad = 1000;
                //match random number corrosponding child in div
                $('#container').children().eq(parseFloat(rand))
                .animate({padding: ap, background : ab}, {duration:ad});
                alert(rand);
            }
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You let your `maxcount` drop below zero but still your function is being called every 100ms (due to your `setInterval`).

So you should clear that interval eventually by doing:

```
/* first */
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){counter();}, 100); 

/* later */
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer as correct if it solved your problem. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the function at a rate of 10 times per second (`setInterval`). Eventually, the `maxcount` variable will drop below 0, causing the `else` condition to execute.

You should store the interval call in a variable, and use `clearInterval` at else, so that the function runs only once after `else`:

```
//Store a reference to the interval
var interval = setInterval(function(){counter();}, 100);
...
function counter(){
    ...
    else if(..){
        ...
        clearInterval(interval); //Clear the previously defined interval
    }
...
```

Another note: In the code, `speed;` has no use. Either prefix it by `var` (`var speed;`), or remove it.

Comment: Ah, of course, thank you. Is there an easy way of getting the function to stop running once it reaches the end of the `else` condition? Like a `returnfalse()` or something (I'm new to JS/jQuery)?

Comment: See my answer. Prefix `setInterval(..)` by `var interval = setInterval(...)`, and add `clearInterval(interval)` before the closing curly bracet (of `else`).

Comment: @Luke I posted earlier. Did you read my full answer before commenting, or did you skip the last part?

Comment: I never noticed your last sentence. You're right though, not sure why that is in there, I've removed it now. Thanks for spotting.